# Trying to network mount a new exfat 6Tb hard drive for network windows 10 access, all instructions tried but still 'no such file or directory' error

Tags: 20.04, mount, hard-drive, samba, fstab

I've looked at all previous posts and tried many suggestions/things, but I still can't mount my new hard drive to enable network access (via smb and for windows 10).
Basically this is for my windows computers to use as backup location.

I've tried a ton of different fstab stuff and all I ever get is this error:
mount error(2): No such file or directory

here is my fstab entries for this drive (the drive mounts locally no problem I can transfer files).

```
UUID=BEE3-E4B0 /media/abemd/Ububak01   auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

//192.168.0.107/share /media/abemd/Ububak01 cifs credentials=/home/abemd/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

I have made a proper .smbcredentials file and chmod 600 as others suggested.
Of course I have latest cifs and samba installed.

Ubuntu version 20.04 lts.

I've been trying to figure this out for a week now and sheesh!! I've done this before no problem, I feel like I'm missing something obvious and stupid. It's driving me crazy.

Thanks for any help.

p.s. here is the result of 'mount' for this drive:

```
/dev/sdc on /media/abemd/Ububak01 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,x-gvfs-show)
```

Comment: During boot, `fstab` mounts are attempted before network comes up and therefore remote mounts fail. In order for these to mount correctly you need to add `_netdev` in the mount's options.

Comment: Please edit your original post and add to it the output of the following commands: `testparm -s` AND `net usershare info --long`